# C Programming segfault when iterating through directories

Tags: c, multithreading, directory, segmentation-fault, iteration

I am needing to walk a directory and perform a sort of grep on each file I come across.

Here is some code, I have the function kicked off in a thread because I want to main to continue with it's tasks. For some reason 
it finishes the iteration and then segfaults.

Why is this segfaulting? What am I doing wrong? How should I fix this?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
 int ccn = 1;

  if(ccn == 1){
  pthread_t thread_id;
      char *path = ".";
    pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, list_dir("."), (void*) path);
}
   /*code continues 
    ...
    ...
   */
 }
```

>

```
void *list_dir (const char * dir_name)
{
    DIR * d;

    /* Open the directory specified by "dir_name". */

    d = opendir (dir_name);

    /* Check it was opened. */
    if (! d) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (1) {
        struct dirent * entry;
        const char * d_name;

        /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
        entry = readdir (d);
        if (! entry) {
            /* There are no more entries in this directory, so break
               out of the while loop. */
            break;
        }
        d_name = entry->d_name;
        /* Print the name of the file and directory. */
    printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);

#if 0
    /* If you don't want to print the directories, use the
       following line: */

        if (! (entry->d_type & DT_DIR)) {
        printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);
    }

#endif /* 0 */


        if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {

            /* Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. */

            if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 &&
                strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {
                int path_length;
                char path[PATH_MAX];

                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,
                                        "%s/%s", dir_name, d_name);
                printf ("%s\n", path);
                if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
                list_dir (path);
            }
    }
    }
    /* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
    if (closedir (d)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0; // This is demanded for a void * ...
}
```

Comment: See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: `pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, list_dir("."), (void*) path);` -> `pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, list_dir, path);`

Comment: `void *list_dir (const char * dir_name) {`-> `void *list_dir (void *arg) { const char *dir_name = arg;`

Comment: `list_dir(".")` **calls** the function, evaluating to its return value. You want to pass a pointer to the function!

Comment: @FelixPalmen I think that should be made into answers, as OP appear to not know how `pthread_create` works.

Comment: I agree with some edits , but I feel it's important to say thank you. At least leave that in.

Comment: @ApertureSecurity no, that's irrelevant chit-chat. If someone gives a complete answer (I commented the relevant parts ...), accept it to say "thank you" ;)

Comment: @ApertureSecurity That's not how [so] works, as indicated in the meta post above. Just like how you don't say thanks on Wikipedia.

Comment: @FelixPalmen well spotted!  It's easy to miss that the function is being called instead of threaded off, (with the inevitable bang when the thread does get started with the function result instead of the function address).

Comment: Ok, as nobody else wanted to do the work, I wrote an answer ;)

Comment: Can we clean up the comment thread? cc @FelixPalmen

Comment: Suggest reading the MAN pages for `pthread_create()`  `pthread_join()`  and `pthread_exit()`  then properly using those functions in your code

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: the check for a directory name of "." is ok, but also need to check for a directory name of ".."

Comment: before: `d_name = entry->d_name;`  also need to check if the type of entry is another directory or other than a regular file.  In general, symbolic (and other links) should be ignored and when the entry is  directory, should dive into the new directory. When done with a directory listing, drop back to the prior directory to finish it.  There are LOTs of examples of how to walk through a directory structure on stackoverflow.  Suggest searching for and reading them

Comment: it is a bad idea to recursively call `list_dir()` as that is a thread

Comment: '0' is not necessarily a void pointer to be used in the exit from a thread. Suggest `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: the posted code is missing all the `#include` statements for the needed header files.   Do you expect us to guess as to which header files you actually included?

Comment: @user3629249 `0` is an integer literal, but implicitly convertible to `void *` and the result is the null pointer, so it's absolutely correct to write it this way.

Comment: @FelixPalmen,  implicit conversions is a sign of sloppy code.

Comment: @user3629249 That's nonesense, at least for C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, list_dir("."), (void*) path);
```

`pthread_create()` expects a pointer to the function the new thread should execute. But writing `list_dir(".")` **calls** the function (before even calling `pthread_create()`). Whatever it returns is fed to `pthread_create()` as the address of the function to execute in the thread.

In your case, you do `return 0` at the end of your function, so `pthread_create()` will try to dereference the *nullpointer* when finally starting the thread, that's the reason for your crash.

To correctly pass the function pointer, you can use the address-of operator (`&list_dir`), or just the identifier of the function, which evaluates as a pointer to the function as well:

```
pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, list_dir, path);
```

I also removed the unnecessary `void *` cast here: Any data pointer can be implicitly converted from and to `void *` in C.

But there's another problem, your function signature currently reads:

```
void *list_dir (const char * dir_name)
```

`pthread_create()` expects a function that takes a `void *` argument. On most platforms, it would actually work the way you wrote it, but it's still wrong and **can** go wrong in practice, because there's no guarantee in C that a `char *` pointer has the same internal representation as a `void *` pointer. So, you **have** to actually do the conversion. Change your function to take `void *` and convert the pointer to the correct type in the first line, e.g. like this:

```
void *list_dir(void *arg) {
    const char *dir_name = arg;
```